# With Angular - Don't Display Array Items based on other Array's Items for Ng-Repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am assuming this has something to do with filter.  I have two arrays: 1. that contains all areas possible to be an administer (called areas) and 2. that contains only the areas that are being administered by the user (called adminAreas which is in an array itself of user).  I have a webpage that shows both in a two column display.  When the user clicks to add them it adds them to the other column and removes itself from the current column.  What I am trying to do is... When the page loads... don't repeat the items in the adminAreas div in the areas div.  Also a cleaner way to do the back and forth adding/removing.

JS:

```
DataService.getAllAreas().then(function (data) {
  $scope.areas = data;
   });

DataService.getUser($scope.userId).then(function(data){
  $scope.user = data;
 });

$scope.assignArea = function (area) {
 $scope.user.adminAreas.push(area.name);
 $scope.areas.splice($scope.areas.indexOf(area), 1);
 DataService.updateUser($scope.user).then(function () {
 });
};

$scope.removeArea = function (areaName) {
 $scope.user.adminAreas.splice($scope.user.adminAreas.indexOf(areaName), 1);
 DataService.updateUser($scope.user).then(function () {
 });
};
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="sideOneAdd" ng-repeat="currentArea in user.adminAreas>
    <a ng-click="assignArea()"><span>{{currentArea}}</span></a>
</div>

 <div class="sideTwoRemove" ng-repeat="area in areas (assuming something with filter)>
    <a ng-click="removeArea()"><span>{{area.name}}</span></a>
 </div>
```

Comment: You must provide some dummy data as an array. It wont be possible to debug without that...

Comment: @Rayon Dabre Not sure if this will help- 

From console: (user) Object > adminAreas > 0: "US"  1: "SA"
From console: (areas) Array [8] > 0: Object > items: --- | name: "SSU" | info: ---
From console: (areas) Array [8] > 1: Object > items: --- | name: "TTA" | info: ---
From console: (areas) Array [8] > 2: Object > items: --- | name: ITA" | info: ---  etc...

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat="area in areas" | filter:filterNotCurrent`

```
$scope.filterNotCurrent = function (area) {
    return !$scope.user.adminAreas.some(function (element) {
        if (element === area)
            return true;
    });
};
```

Comment: well if you use filters... just build a custom filter and pass what you need into it... no need to use controller for that...

Comment: @TomSlick It made the area div empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use this filter :

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .filter('filterAssignedAreas', filterAssignedAreas);

function filterAssignedAreas(){
  return function(areas, assignedAreas){  
    return areas.filter(function(obj){
      return !assignedAreas.some(function(obj2){
        return obj2.name == obj.name;  
      })
    })
  }
}
```

And Then :

```
<div class="sideTwoRemove" ng-repeat="area in areas |   filterAssignedAreas:user.adminAreas">
```